# converting excel spanish dates

Tags: excel

I have spreadsheet with mutliple rows in which a few are dates. The problem is that while some rows are in english date format, few others are in spanish format eg. Octubre 1, 2015, Septiembre 1, 2014 etc. What could be the easiest way to convert all of them into english format dates.

Comment: If this is just formatting, then the underlying values are the same and no conversion of values needed. Did you try just changing the format of the cells that have the Spanish dates?

Answer (score 0):

Give this small macro a try:

```
Sub Converter()
   ary = Split("Enero, January, Febrero, February, Marzo, March, Abril, April, Mayo, May, Junio, June, Julio, July, Agosto, August, Septiembre, September, Octubre, October, Noviembre, November, Diciembre, December", ", ")
   For I = 0 To 23 Step 2
      Cells.Replace What:=ary(I), Replacement:=ary(I + 1)
   Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sub will select all cells containing dates (irrespective of how they are formatted) on the active sheet. If you run it and then right-click on one of the selected cells and select `format cells` from the drop-down menu, you can decide on a common date format:

```
Sub SelectDates()
    Dim dates As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            If dates Is Nothing Then
                Set dates = cell
            Else
                Set dates = Union(dates, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    dates.Select
End Sub
```